# Can't run my beacon app because kontakt sdk error

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, beacon

This is the error when I try to run my app that contains the Kontakt.io dependency: [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33OhL.png)

I am following this tutorial:

> http://developer.kontakt.io/android-sdk/2.0.0/quickstart/

I am using Android Studio and a Samsung J to test it.

Basically, in the tutorial all I need to add to my project is this line in the build.gradle file (module):

```
 dependencies {

 compile 'com.kontakt.sdk.android:kontakt.io-android-sdk:2.0.1'

}
```

And this line in the build.gradle file (project):

```
allprojects {

    repositories {

        jcenter()

        maven { url 'http://repo.kontakt.io/repository/internal/' }  // <-- this line

    }

}
```

So.. any idea what's happening? I know there are repeated files but they are created automatically!! any workaraund?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Kontakt.io Android Proximity SDK https://github.com/kontaktio/kontakt-android-sdk on GitHub.

- Click the Download ZIP button
- Un-zip the file to a temporary location.
- Add the jar file in your Android Studio Project.
- File -> New Module -> Import .JAR/ .AAR Package -> Click Next -> Browse the SDK path (2.1.1) -> Finish
  (Take time to add in the project)
- Then, Add module in dependencies
- Right Click on Project Name -> Open Module Settings -> Under the list (Modules) -> Click on Dependencies -> Click on '+' -> Module Dependency -> Add Kontakt.io-android-sdk

Now Build your project
It worked for me to kontakt io SDK.
If anybody find the way to do this as Gradle build, please let me know.

Comment: It worked for me..it is added the gradle file as follows..compile project(':kontakt.io-android-sdk2.1.1')